# How do I read Querystring variables in a Kooboo Module?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kooboo

I need to be able to pass an ID to my Kooboo module.
I was hoping to add {id} to the page route and then somehow pass it to the module put I can't seem to find how.
I want the Querystring variable to be passed into the MVC Controller action.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure it out

Add a route to a controller in Module.Config

Use
@Url.ModuleUrl().Action("ActionName")
or
@Url.ModuleUrl().Action("ActionName", new { parameterName = 0 })"
To get an url to another action/controller within you module